# Insert rows using data from existing rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, insert

So, I have a mysql table called product_description with columns: primarykey, name, description, language_id (primarykey is an auto-increment field)

It has maybe 18000 records each for language IDs 1 and 2.

I'd like to create new rows copying data from rows for language ID 1.

Could I do something like

```
INSERT INTO 'product_description' ('name', 'description', 'language_id')
VALUES (SELECT 'name', 'description', 3 FROM 'product_description' WHERE 'language_id' = 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO product_description (name, description, language_id)
SELECT name, description, 3 
FROM product_description
WHERE language_id = 1;
```

BTW if you want to escape column or table names, then use backticks, not quotes.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that I don't have to worry about inserting primarykey field?

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks instead of single Quote like this

```
INSERT INTO `product_description` (`name`, `description`, `language_id`)
SELECT `name`, `description`, 3 
FROM `product_description` 
WHERE `language_id` = 1;
```